# Flutter app startup time slow if downloaded from PlayStore but instantaneous if installed via USB

Tags: android, performance, flutter

My app entered the internal testing stage, meaning I upload it to Google Play Store as AAB bundle and then can install it on various devices.

I have noticed that the startup time of the app downloaded from the store is atrociously slow. The splash screen is hanging on for 10 - 15 seconds depending on the device.

On the other hand, if I install the very same app via USB from the dev machine it starts up instantaneously, with the splash screen visible for maximum 1 - 2 seconds.

Also, it looks like it is only the startup time that differs significantly. Regarding the overall performance of the app it is indistinguishable for the version installed via the USB cable and the one downloaded from the store.

I have absolutely no clue why this may be happening and will appreciate any suggestions pointing to what may be causing such behaviour.

Comment: What were the build commands? What do you load on application startup.

Comment: flutter build appbundle --flavor basic -t lib/main_basic.dart --build-name=someName --build-number=someVersion --obfuscate --split-debug-info=aPathToDirectory --no-shrink

Comment: All I load on startup is a small set of preferences (I use the Shared Preferences lib) with literally 5 fields and I also initialise the Hive